# CRichEditCtrl and Unicode BOM

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

I am reading a UTF-16LE file as bytes and sending it to the CRichEditControl.  I find that if the BOM is present, the edit control does not display its context correctly.

My question:  is it my responsibility to strip the BOM, or is there some option that I need to set differently on the edit control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always send data to the rich edit control as UTF-16 LE because that's the standard Windows uses for all strings. The BOM isn't a valid UTF-16 character so you should strip it off.